# Call an API-endpoint and print a message on client side by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I have a very simple assignment for my school, but I just can't figure out how to solve it.
I need to create an endpoint for an API in Node.JS that responds to a GET request - so when I click the button in my HTML file, it should call my API endpoint and print the message "Hello World" and the number of times it has been called in an alert box.

**UPDATED, UPDATED:**

client/index.html

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  </body>
    
    <!-- 
    When clicking this button, an alert needs to show up 
    displaying a GET request from the server.js file with 
    the text "Hello World" a long with a number increasing 
    for each time, the call has been made 
    -->
    <button id="myBtn" type="button" onclick="alertCount()">Send</button>

    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

client/javascript.js

```
function alertCount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000").then(res => {
        console.log("log");
        return res.text()
    }).then(text => {
        alert(text)
    })
};
```

server/server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
let counter = 0;

app.use(express.static('client'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('"Hello World!" has been called ' + counter + ' time(s).');
    ++counter;
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening..."));
```

Comment: It looks like the endpoint (server.js) is more or less correct. It's the client that needs some work - you'll need to send an AJAX request to the server when the button is pressed, and you will need some JavaScript that updates the page content based on the response, in order to display the counter.

Comment: Thank you @Dan for your input. It is very much appreciated. But I am kind of a noob with javascript and especially API requests. Could you perhaps give me a few more hints on how to send an AJAX request to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a function in the onclick handler of the button. See an example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick)

```js
// javascript.js
function myFunction() {
  fetch("https://5f7203e364a3720016e61337.mockapi.io/text").then(res => {
    return res.text()
  }).then(text => {
    alert(text)
  })
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

EDIT: updated the script, all you need to do is replace the url inside the fetch()

Comment: Thank you for your answer  @Tasos Bu.
But how do I print the number of times the API has been called in an alert box?

Comment: Thank you again for your answer @Tasos Bu. It is very appreciated.
But I think you are misunderstanding my issue. 

When clicking the button, I need for my small project to make an API request to the server.js file and get the "Hello World" text from that file, and display it on the index.html file in an alert,  with the number of requests next to it.
So, when I click the button the first time, and alert should say "Hello World!" has been called 1 time(s)."
The second time it should say "... was called 2 time(s)" and so on.

Comment: This is what i've done with my snippet above. This snippet is your index.html file and all you need to do is use your own api url to call your server.js

Comment: See how I import the javascript.js file in the index.html file

Comment: Thank you once again @Tasos Bu. Once more it is very appreciated! 
But when I do as you describe (see my edited files above), I get an error in my console saying _"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"_ and an alert shows the entire HTML code from the index file.

Comment: The API url is wrong. You don't call the path to the file. Change it to `http://localhost:3000/`